# Hibernate : How to Join 3 tables in one join table by Annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, join

I have some roles, users and applications
I want to create a mapping hibernate of this table :

```
CREATE TABLE role_application_user (
  role_identifier INTEGER not null,
  application_identifier INTEGER not null,
  user_identifier INTEGER not null,
  KEY FK_role_identifier (role_identifier),
  KEY FK_application_identifier(application_identifier),
  KEY FK_user_identifier (user_identifier),
  CONSTRAINT FK_role_identifier FOREIGN KEY (role_identifier) REFERENCES role (identifier),
  CONSTRAINT FK_application_identifier FOREIGN KEY (application_identifier) REFERENCES application (identifier),
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_identifier FOREIGN KEY (user_identifier) REFERENCES users (login)
);
```

for an application, a role can have many users and a user can of many roles.

I try this mapping :

Application.java

```
@JoinTable(name = "role_application_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "application_identifier"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_identifier"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "role_identifier")
@ElementCollection
private Map<Role, User> userByRole = new HashMap<>();
```

Unfortunately, this is not working in my case because in java, the key of a Map must be unique.

With this mapping, we can have only one user for a role and an application.

Comment: Here is your answer https://developer.jboss.org/thread/168634?tstart=0

Comment: you got the solution?

Answer (score 2):

try this implementation :

```
    @Entity
    public class User {
        @OneToMany
        private List<RoleInApplication> rolesInApplications;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Role {
        @OneToMany
        private List<RoleInApplication> rolesInApplications;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class RoleInApplication {
        @ManyToOne
        private User user;
        @ManyToOne
        private Role role;
        @ManyToOne
        private Application application;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Application {
        @OneToMany
        private List<RoleInApplication> rolesInApplications;
    }
```

Comment: This one is ok. But it allows duplicate in RoleInApplication entity. How to prevent that?

Comment: Did you try with a composite key on RoleInApplication? @Rajesh

Comment: Yes Bro. I made it like that and ok.