# How to map three tables in hibernate annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

My question is pretty same like the below question.

[Hibernate : How to Join 3 tables in one join table by Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591170/hibernate-how-to-join-3-tables-in-one-join-table-by-annotation)

As I didn't any answer there I am asking here again.
I have user,role,application tables. How to map this in annotation. I tried like below.

```
@JoinTable(name = "role_application_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "application_identifier"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_identifier"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "role_identifier")
@ElementCollection
private Map<Role, User> userByRole = new HashMap<>();
```

But by this I can't assign more than one application/role access. I need to have all the possible options to assign. What I am doing wrong here?

I want something like this in the final join table.

```
UserID RoleID ApplicationID
1      1      1
1      1      2
1      1      3
1      2      1
1      3      1
2      1      1
```

Here is my entity class

**User.java**

```
Class User{

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "CTC_AC_USER_INSTITUTION", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "institutionId")})
private Set<Institution> institutions = new HashSet<Institution>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "CTC_AC_USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userProfileId")})
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
```

}

**UserProfile.java**

```
Class UserProfile {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type", length = 25, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();
}
```

**Institution.java**

```
Class Institution{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Length(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: why you can't use @Mohamed Nabli solution ? from prev question

Comment: Show your entity classes.

Comment: updated the question with pojos